# Storing CLOB data with jdbc to Oracle 9i database

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle9i

I am facing problems to store CLOB data through JDBC to Oracle 9i database. I am using PreparedStatement and setting the data as setString(index, value). The value is a large XML string. The driver I am using is ojdbc14.jar. Still I am getting an error saying " java.lang.Exception: Data size bigger than max size for this type: 4723".

My XML is not so big that it will not fit in CLOB field. Still getting this error. Please help.

I searched various sites it it did not solve the problem, the setClob() method is not supported by ojdbc14 driver.

Answer (score 0):

The XML probably isn't too big for a CLOB (4GB!) but is for using `setString` (4000 characters). The textbook solution would probably be to use the [`setCharacterStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setCharacterStream-int-java.io.Reader-int-) method instead:

```
PreparedStatement ps = ...;
String xml = "<xml>somve verly long data... </xml>";

ps.setCharacterStream(1, new StringReader(xml), xml.length());
```

Comment: I tried this method, this is not throwing an exception and the other fields are getting inserted, but the CLOB field is not getting inserted